# Possible causes for error: Field cannot be both deferred and traversed using select_related at the same time?

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to use `graphene-django-optimizer` to remove some of the unnecessary queries. It worked quite well until one certain field where I get this error message `Field User.company cannot be both deferred and traversed using select_related at the same time`. The only difference with this field is that it is `models.OneToOne` instead of `models.ForeignKey`. Why Django make this field deferred? Is it possible to disable field being deferred?

Comment: maybe you are using `.only()` on queryset

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you do this:

```
queryset.select_related('some_fk_field').only('another_field')
```

You may miss that there is a conflict. You are telling Django ORM to include some_fk_field, but you are also telling it to limit the query to *only* retrieve another_field, so it complains it can't do it.
You use .only() to exclude absolutely everything that is not detailed, but .select_related() is trying to do the opposite requesting some extra elements. To make it even clearer (and this is how I found out), here is the Django source code that handles this case:

```
    if load_fields:
        if field.attname not in load_fields:
            if restricted and field.name in requested:
                raise InvalidQuery("Field %s.%s cannot be both deferred"
                                   " and traversed using select_related"
                                   " at the same time." %
                                   (field.model._meta.object_name, field.name))
```

Source:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/_modules/django/db/models/query_utils/

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what Emilio said, to solve this issue the query should be re-arranged to this

```
queryset.select_related('some_fk_field').only('another_field', 'some_fk_field')
```

The `.only()` tells django to pull out only the `some_fk_field` and `another_field` then since the `some_fk_field` is a foreign key the `select_related()` pulls out the `some_fk_field` object too and that fixes the error you are getting